# Cause one textbox to validate other textboxes/dropdowns

Tags: forms, validation, powershell, textbox

I am trying to make a form textbox in PowerShell in which I can paste data into the first textbox and have it auto populate to several other fields when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I managed to get that part working fine, but the various validation steps that those other fields normally have don't work when filled out in this way.

Here's a sample of what I am talking about:

```psh
$InputTextBox.Add_Validating(CODE SEGMENT 1)
$DescriptionTextBox.Add_Validating(CODE SEGMENT 2)
$SplitComboBox.Add_Validating(CODE SEGMENT 3)
```

Is there anything I can put in `CODE SEGMENT 1` to trigger `CODE SEGMENT 2` and `CODE SEGMENT 3` to run as well? Is there another way to do this with a different approach?

Edit:
When I tab out of `$inputTextBox`, it splits up the input there and distributes it to the other fields with `$DescriptionTextBox.Text = $Description` and `$SplitComboBox.SelectedItem = $Split`.

When that is done though, the values entered do not trigger the contents of `Add_Validating()` to run.

Comment: The validation steps don't work when what is filled out what way? When you programmatically change the other fields with the contents from the text box the values you insert aren't validated?

Comment: When i tab out of $inputTextBox, it splits up the input there and distributes it to the other fields with $DescriptionTextBox.Text = $Description and $SplitComboBox.SelectedItem = $Split

When that is done though, the values entered do not trigger the contents of Add_Validating() to run

Comment: And the normal validation that applies to user input to those other fields is not being run? That's the issue?

Comment: Can't you just add `$DescriptionTextBox.Invalidate()` and/or `$DescriptionTextBox.Update()` to the end of your `CODE SEGMENT 1` code? Then add the same thing for `$SplitComboBox.Invalidate()/Update()`?

Comment: Well, that's what i was asking, If there was a command for that. That does seem to have worked, thanks.